# responsive issue with bootstrap on mobile and tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Site: http://www.partyfacepainting.co.uk/test

Bootstraps responsive features don't seem to be working on iPhone or iPad for this site for some reason. They work fine on the desktop when I reduce the size of the browser window. I've searched the topic and the only answer seems to be in relation to not adding:

```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
> initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

but I have this in and it's still not responsive. I have created a few sites with bootstrap now and never had this problem in the past. I have even tried uploading an unedited version of the bootstrap files with one of their starter templates as the index file (you can see that here: http://www.partyfacepainting.co.uk) and even that's not working. I just can't figure this out! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to have that meta viewport for mobile. RWD would work ok on desktop even with or without viewport meta tag. Your test site currently don't have the viewport meta tag therefore it wouldn't work.

Comment: If you put your site in an iframe, which is not a good idea for many reasons, and the originating frame page's html doesn't have the viewport meta tag, this is what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is structured like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Party Face Painting</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <!-- you need a viewport meta tag up here -->
  </head>
  <frameset rows="100%">
    <frame ...>
      #document
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            ...
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <!-- you have a viewport meta tag within the frameset here -->
            ...
          </head>
          ...
    </frame>
    ...
  </frameset>
</html>
```

You do not have a viewport meta tag on the outermost page, only within the frame

Comment: can't believe I missed this!! thanks so much for your help :-)

Comment: @DuncanMacnaughtan - please accept this answer so you can be a participating member of the community